# IF...ELSE conditional always return ELSE conditional

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple query like this:

```
@DesignKey [INT] = NULL
AS
        BEGIN
            -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
            -- interfering with SELECT statements.
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            -- Insert statements for procedure here
            IF(@DesignKey != NULL)
            BEGIN
                 SELECT
                     [P].[LegacyKey] AS [Job No]
                   , [TT].[Name] AS [Task]
                   , CONCAT([E].[FirstName] , ' ' , [E].[MaidenName]) AS [Technician]
                    FROM [Task] AS [T]
                        LEFT JOIN [TaskAssignation] AS [TA] ON [T].[TaskAssignationId] = [TA].[TaskAssignationId]
                        LEFT JOIN [Employee] AS [E] ON [TA].[EmpKey] = [E].[EmpKey]
                        INNER JOIN [TaskType] AS [TT] ON [T].[TaskTypeId] = [TT].[TaskTypeId]
                        INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [T].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
                        INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
                        INNER JOIN [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
                    WHERE [E].[EmpKey] IS NOT NULL
                         AND [T].[DesignKey] = @DesignKey
            END
               ELSE
            BEGIN
                             SELECT
                    [P].[LegacyKey] AS [Job No]
                   , [TT].[Name] AS [Task]
                   , CONCAT([E].[FirstName] , ' ' , [E].[MaidenName]) AS [Technician]
                    FROM [Task] AS [T]
                        LEFT JOIN [TaskAssignation] AS [TA] ON [T].[TaskAssignationId] = [TA].[TaskAssignationId]
                        LEFT JOIN [Employee] AS [E] ON [TA].[EmpKey] = [E].[EmpKey]
                        INNER JOIN [TaskType] AS [TT] ON [T].[TaskTypeId] = [TT].[TaskTypeId]
                        INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [T].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
                        INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
                        INNER JOIN [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
                    WHERE [E].[EmpKey] IS NOT NULL

            END
        END
```

As you can see it will execute different selects depending if @DesignKey comes null or not, so I execute query as:

```
exec usp_Get_EmpoyeeByDesign
```

and it runs correctly it execute second select now if I send @DesignKey as:

```
exec usp_Get_EmpoyeeByDesign @DesignKey = 2837
```

It load same result, it doesn't take care my `if` conditional I test it sending parameter of designKey in where clause as:

```
WHERE [E].[EmpKey] IS NOT NULL
                         AND [T].[DesignKey] = 2837
```

and it  throws desire results. So in conclusion query don't validate if @DesignKey come or not. What is wrong there? Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace     `!= NULL`    with   `IS NOT NULL`.

Any operation with NULL returns NULL, not True.

Think of NULL as meaning "I don't know".

You have two baskets of apples.  One of them has 7 apples.  The other basket is covered so you don't know how many apples there are. Do the two baskets have the same number apples?  Do they have a different number of apples?

```
declare @a int, @b int
set @a = 7    -- 7 apples
set @b = NULL -- I don't know how many apples

if @a = @b 
  print 'Equal' -- doesn't print

if @a <> @b 
  print 'Not equal' -- doesn't print
```

Since you don't know how many apples are in the second bucket you can't know that the number of apples are equal, nor can you know whether they are not equal.

Comment: That's one of the best explanations of `Null` that I've seen, David.

Comment: I created this simple explanation using baskets of fruit, and it has served me well. Apply it to NULL=NULL and it's intuitively obvious why it's not True. (and not False).  It even holds up dealing with AND, OR, NOT, IN, NOT IN, and many other more complex expressions.

Comment: I bet it has - it's brilliant.  I am SO stealing it.